# SQL Query Summing In Join

Tags: sql

I have two tables

**Table_1:**

```
╔══════╦══════════╦═════════╗
║ Name ║   Date   ║ Revenue ║
╠══════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║  A   ║ 1/1/2001 ║   20    ║
║  A   ║ 1/2/2001 ║   20    ║
║  B   ║ 1/1/2001 ║   40    ║
╚══════╩══════════╩═════════╝
```

**Table_2:**

```
╔══════╦══════╗
║ Name ║ Task ║
╠══════╬══════╣
║  A   ║ Call ║
║  A   ║ Foo  ║
║  B   ║ Bar  ║
╚══════╩══════╝
```

So I do a join

```
SELECT sum(Revenue), t2.Name, T2.Task
FROM Table_1 as t1 JOIN Table_2 as t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name
GROUP BY t2.Name
```

The result table of the join looks like this:

```
Result
Name    Sum
A       80
B       40
```

The problem is that I want the sum result of A to be 40. How should I modify my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Revenue)
FROM Table_1
GROUP BY Name
```

I don't see any point in joining `Table_1` to `Table_2` since you are not making use of the `Task` column.

Comment: Perhaps he's using it as a filter i.e. only show rows which also exist in Table_2.

Comment: Also you should explain *why* he got 80 in his query, it's a good teaching opportunity.

Comment: He gets 80 because when he joins on name, it returns 4 rows where Name = A (2 rows from table_1 times 2 rows from table_2). 4 * 20 = 80

Comment: @Kyle Of course you are right.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Forgot to add Task to the select clause.

Comment: How do you want the `Task` to appear?  Can you also update your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

The root of your problem is that the join is not doing what you expect it to do.  By doing the join between the two tables on the 'name', you are creating duplicates.  Remove the group by clause in your query and you will see exactly what I mean.

As mentioned in a previous answer, the join (in this case) is superfluous.  I would advise looking at things closer than that.  How could the data be structured such that this duplication of data doesn't occur?

Without more data I can't provide you any more direction, but hopefully my comments will point you in the right direction and you'll learn a valuable lesson on using discrete key values.

Comment: Forgot to add Task to the select clause

Answer (score 0):

you have to calculate the sum before joining the tables like:

```
    select t1.Name, t1.sum, t2.task from
    (
      SELECT Name, sum(Revenue) as sum FROM Table_1 group by Name
    ) as t1 
   JOIN 
   Table_2 as t2 ON t1.Name = t2.Name
```